# Revising Sierpinski Triangle with Buttons

Tags: java, javafx, fractals

The problem is revising the code for the Sierpinski Triangle and putting buttons with plus and minus buttons to make the triangle bigger or smaller. The problem I am having is where to put the buttons in the code. I have the code for the original Sierpinski Triangle.

Relevant JavaFX code:

```
@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  SierpinskiTrianglePane trianglePane = new SierpinskiTrianglePane();
  Button btnPlus = new Button("+");
  Button btnMinus = new Button("-");
  btnPlus.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
  HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
  hBox.getChildren().addAll(btnPlus, btnMinus);
  hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
  BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
  borderPane.setCenter(trianglePane);
  borderPane.setBottom(hBox););
}
```

Comment: We obviously cannot point to the right line number without seeing any code, so please give us something to work with. At least, tell us what you use for creating buttons, java-swing or something like that?

Comment: @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage){
 SierpinskiTrianglePane trianglePane = new SierpinskiTrianglePane();
 Button btnPlus = new Button("+");
 Button btnMinus = new Button("-");
 
 btnPlus.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
 
 HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
 hBox.getChildren().addAll(btnPlus, btnMinus);
 hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
 
 BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
 borderPane.setCenter(trianglePane);
 borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
 );
  }

Comment: Next time, if you want to add something to your question, you can modify it by clicking the "edit" button. Comments are less suitable for code listings. Code listings are created by indenting the code by four empty spaces.

Comment: The problem is I dont know where to put the code for the buttons.

Comment: I could help you with Java/Swing, but I don't know anything about JavaFX, therefore I can not help you with your problem. My comments addressed the form of your question. The code in your comment was unreadable, so I formatted it and added to your question. Hopefully this increased the chance that someone who knows JavaFX answers the question.

Comment: Are you asking where to put code that is invoked when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Recently started working on this problem and i'm actually using a sample resource from the 'Intro to Java Programming book'. You can review the original code [here](http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/intro9e/html/SierpinskiTriangle.html). I basically modified the method used to initialize all the JApplet elements.

I first initialized the button using the generic call structure

```
panel.add(buttonPlus);
```

Then i wired it up to a listener class to track the button clicks

```
   buttonPlus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            trianglePanel.setOrder(value + 1);
            value += 1;
            panel.add(new JLabel("Sierpinski number: " + value));
        }
    });
```

As for your solution, you can try initializing the button where you set the Sierpinski Triangle

Sorry for my bad explanation, a newbie here.